# Passing the atrribute information along to LLVM

Tags: llvm, clang

I've created a new attribute in clang using the steps detailed in
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html
What's the best way 
of passing the atrribute information along to LLVM?

Comment: Metadata, of course. See how OpenCL '__kernel' attribute is implemented in Clang, for example.

Comment: @SK-logic can you provide some example of how to do it, I saw OPENCL but still confused little bit

Comment: Take a look at `lib/CodeGen/CodeGenFunction.cpp`, search for "opencl.kernels" string.